# Using WebClient.DownloadFile when you don't know the filetype

Tags: c#, download, httprequest

Essentially I'm making an HTTP request where my endpoint is a `domain.com/id/download/platform` where my header accepts `*/*`.

The file type returned depends upon the id given, so my web client would be defined like this:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.Headers.Add("Accept", "*/*")
...
string filename = "name.*";
webResource = this.URI + fileName;
client.DownloadFile(myStringResource, fileName);
```

This obviously won't work, but could I make WebClient work in this context when I don't know what the root URL file type is?
Also, I don't have a path directly to that file so how would i get it if my endpoint looks like the endpoint provided above?

Comment: `"The file type returned depends upon the id given"` Do a switch on the id to build the full uri to do the web request on.

Comment: @JaredBeach Those ids are generated by the api, so I would have to update that everytime another object was created

Comment: Maybe you need to store those ID's in a database then and query the filetype to build the URL

Comment: Then you'd update the database when a new object is added

Comment: Using an extension to mark file types is a Windowsism. HTTP works exclusively through `Content-Type`. If you server chooses to vary the URL to include the extension based on file type, that's fine for improving the experience of a user who downloads through a browser, but you will still need to *know* the URL in advance. In that sense, your question can be answered with a simple "ask the person who made these endpoints". One possible solution is to use a neutral endpoint name (no extension) and serve the desired filename in a `Content-Disposition` header.